# The difference between flex:1 and flex-grow:1

Tags: css, flexbox

In [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

- `flex:1`

means the same as

- `flex-grow:1`.

However, in fact it has different show in browser.

You can try it in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh6uo8g2/) by changing the comment in css.

When I use `flex: 1` the element who's classname is `test-container` will be `height:100%` but it won't happen when you use `flex-grow: 1`.

I don't understand why. Looking for some help. Thanks very much.

```css
.flex-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.child-1 {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.child-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* flex:1; */
  background: green;
}

.test-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-1">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2">
    <div class="test-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### `flex`

The [**`flex`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) property is a shorthand for setting:

- `flex-grow`
- `flex-shrink`
- `flex-basis`

The `flex: 1` rule is supposed to compute to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

These values are defined in the spec. See section [7.1.1. Basic Values of `flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

I say *"supposed to compute"* because, in IE11 and possibly other browsers, a unit of measure, such as `px` or `%`, is appended to the `0` value in `flex-basis`. This can make a difference ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276)).

---

### `flex-grow`

The [**flex-grow**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property) property (which distributes free space in the container among flex items), when declared by itself, leaves `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` at their initial values.

So when you set `flex-grow: 1`, the browser renders this:

- `flex-grow: 1`     ([overrides the default value, which is 0](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-property))
- `flex-shrink: 1`   ([this is the default value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property))
- `flex-basis: auto` ([this is the default value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property))

---

### The difference between `flex: 1` and `flex-grow: 1`

Ultimately, the difference between `flex: 1` and `flex-grow: 1` is that the former sets `flex-basis: 0`, and the latter keeps the default `flex-basis: auto`.

For a complete explanation of the difference between `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-basis: auto` see this post:

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)

---

### Your code example

The reason you're seeing a difference in your code is that `flex-basis` controls height in a column-direction container.

In Chrome, with `flex-basis: auto`, the height of the element is 450px (500px parent - 50px header). In other words, `flex-grow` is free to distribute the free space.

With `flex-basis: 0`, the height of the element is 0, and `flex-grow` has no free space to distribute.

The `height: 100%` on the child of the flex item is simply ignored because it isn't being applied properly, as explained in these posts:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)

In reading the posts above you'll also understand why your code renders differently in Firefox, Safari, Edge and IE.

Comment: first of all ,thanks for you help.after read all of the posts you given.l get the reason of my code example is that when `flex-basis` is `auto`,`height:100%` doesn't work because the container's height is none.when you set the `flex-basis` a specific value the `height:100%` can get the `height of what`. You say the `flex-basis:auto` make the element height is 450px.if the element is 450px why the `height:100%` doesn't work? The container element alreday has a specific height.

Comment: The element is 450px tall because of `flex-grow: 1`, not because of `height: 100%`.

Comment: l agree 'the element is 450px tall because of `flex-grow:1`, not because of `height:100%`'.However, no matter the value of `flex-basis` is what , the height of the container element(who's background is green) will be 450px. Accroding to the [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520932/make-flex-grow-expand-items-based-on-their-original-size). When the `flex-basis:0` the child element's(who's background is white) height should be 0 and `flex-grow` is free to distribute the free space(450px).

Comment: When the `flex-basis:auto` the basis of the child element will be 0 too.it doesn't have a specific height or some content.it's just a empty `div`.So there still has 450px to distribute.In my opinion, the difference between the two value is the specific value of height.Maybe l walk to a wrong direction, thank you again.

Comment: See my last two link references. There is confusion because browsers render percentage heights differently in flex containers. It's not consistent or reliable.

Comment: than you very much.l understand now.great answer

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I can't find words to thank you. I'm so grateful for all your answers related to the flexbox. Now I can say I understand flexbox. another request please could you suggest any useful resources and great as your answers to read about Grid layout?

Answer (score 1):

l get the reason why that happen. In fact

`flex:1` === `flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;flex-basis:0%`

the key is the `flex-basis:0%`. If you use `flex-grow:1`,the `flex-basis` will be auto. In this sutation, you can't let the `height:100%` work .

However I don't sure when the

`flex:1` === `flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;flex-basis:0%`

will happen. In the doc

`flex:1` !== `flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;flex-basis:0%`